# Apache redirect with Query parameter

Tags: wordpress, apache

I am new to wordpress, i have a situiation where i have to redirect an url with query params to a new url. can some one please help me out with it . i tried few things but none of it works

here is the url pattern

http://exampledomain.com/page/?p=job/123

i want it to redirect to

http://newdomain.com/jobs/123

Comment: So _what_ have you tried?

Comment: arkascha beat me to the punch with a very good answer.  To elaborate: 1) your best bet it probably to create a "rewrite" in [.htaccess](https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/216456227--htaccess-overview), 2) Since you're basing it on the query parameter, you need a "RewriteRule".  Here is a good link that better explains what's going on here: [How can I redirect and rewrite my URLs with an .htaccess file?](https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/215747748-How-can-I-redirect-and-rewrite-my-URLs-with-an-htaccess-file-)

Answer (score 1):

This probably is what you are looking for:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^|&p=job/(\d+)&|$
RewriteRule ^/?page/?&p /jobs/%1 [R=301]

RewriteRule ^/?jobs/(\d+)$) /page/?p=job/$1 [END]
```

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using that rule chances are that you operate an old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in that case in the http server's error log file. Either upgrade the http server or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same here, though that depends a but on your setup.

That rule should work likewise in the http server's host configuration or in a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" style file). You should prefer the first option, but if you really have to use a dynamic configuation file then take care that the interpretation of such files is enabled at all in the http server configuration and that the file is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).